# Is it possible revert iTunes backup from Time Machine?

Tags: itunes, time-machine

My iPhone went wrong and last time I didn't backed it up in iTunes, but earlier I do. And earlier I used often Time Machine. Do you think it is possible get back and revert an iPhone application?

Is iTunes backup part of the Time Machine saving scope?

---

I found that iTunes backup is stored on this path:

```
/Volumes/backup/Backups.backupdb/MacBook Air/2016-12-05-113511/Névtelen/Users/kukodajanos/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

But subfolders are hashed. So how to revert? I have a newer Mac, not restored from this back. How can I choose the right version of iTunes backup?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder named with 40 random chars in Backup folder is your iOS backup (40 cahrs is the UDID of your device).

You will need to restore the "cd84f21616..." folder back to default iTunes backup folder: users/*user*/Library/ApplicationSupport/MobileSync/Backup.

After this, you should see your backup in iTunes and be able to restore it.